# Autofill Method of Range class failed while populating table

Tags: vba, excel, range, autofill

I'm currently working on a project in Excel that take raw data and places it into a table. Currently The table resizes based on the size of the data being copied into it. The issue I am having is that the majority of the tale is filled with formulas based on the data. I am trying to autofill the formulas to the end of the table based on the size as determined from the data and get the error "Autofill method of range class failed"

```
ColNo = 26 + ((large - Year(Date)) * 4)
ColLet = Split(Cells(, ColNo).Address, "$")(1)

Sheets(sheetsSA).Range("V3:W4").AutoFill Destination:=Sheets(sheetsSA).Range("V3:W" & semi_end + 1)
 ****Sheets(sheetsSA).Range("X3:Y4").AutoFill Destination:=Sheets(sheetsSA).Range("X3:" & ColLet & semi_end + 1)****
```

The starred line is the one giving the issue. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. The first two lines find the letter of the column which is used in the autofill.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AutoFill` command expects the entire column width in the first part of the range argument.

This line of code should work:

```
Sheets(sheetsSA).Range("X3:" & ColLet & "4").AutoFill Destination:=Sheets(sheetsSA).Range("X3:" & ColLet & semi_end + 1)
```

Furthemore, you'd be search well with a [`With End With Statement'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx)

```
With Sheets(sheetsSA)
    .Range("V3:W4").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("V3:W" & semi_end + 1)
    .Range("X3:" & ColLet & "4").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("X3:" & ColLet & semi_end + 1)
End With
```

Comment: Thank you very much Scott, this worked great! I was unaware that the entire column width was expected in the first part of the argument. Thanks for the help.

Comment: yes, intuitively, if you think about it makes sense. you have to know the exact range to you want to based the fill on before you can fill :)

Comment: Agreed, the more I think about it the more sense it makes. I'm still fairly new to VBA and Excel. I appreciate your help :)